# How to compile class which extends my fragment

Tags: android, class, kotlin, constructor, compilation

In kotlin I have two fragments - first fragment and second fragment, which extends first fragment. But during compiling of my app I have an error:

> FragmentAllTags.kt: (9, 20): Primary constructor call expected.

Please, help me fix this error for child class, to for constructor without params called constructor with empty list argument, and if I will call constructor with param - variable get value of param from constructor, i.e as it works in parent class.

Parent class:

```
open class FragmentAllCategories(var categories: MutableList<ModelCategory>) : Fragment() {
constructor(): this(mutableListOf<ModelCategory>()) {
}
…
}
```

child class:

```
class FragmentAllTags(categories: MutableList<ModelCategory>): FragmentAllCategories(categories) {
    constructor(): super() {

    }
…
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a primary constructor, the secondary constructors cannot call super constructors. They have to call the primary constructor.

A Fragment's primary constructor should always be empty, because the framework can destroy and recreate it, and it recreates it by calling the empty constructor. Therefore, your FragmentAllCategories code would not be able to rely on the `categories` collection having the items you first passed to it. So if you instantiate your Fragment with some Categories and start it, if the screen rotates or the app goes to the background and comes back, those ModelCategories will be gone.

To avoid this problem, you can put the `categories` collection in an Activity-scoped ViewModel, which will survive screen rotations and app-backgrounding. Or you can make your ModelCategory a Parcelable and add it to the Fragment's bundle before you first start it. The bundle will automatically be restored when the Fragment is recreated.

Comment: But i want to use this fragments in several activities. Why for parent class all works ok,but for child class i have this error. As i understood,there is no way to fix this error,to all constructors for child class,works as for parent class. I want for constructor without params have empty mutable list <ModelCategory> for my class property. How i can do it,as it works for parent class?

Comment: The parent class's secondary constructor is calling its own primary constructor, not a super constructor, so it compiles. But what I'm saying is, this won't work how you expect at runtime when you rotate the screen. This is why every single example of a Fragment in the Android documentation has an empty constructor, and when arguments are needed, a factory pattern is used and the factory converts the arguments into a Bundle.